# Removing double quotes from a string with javascript

Tags: javascript

I've got a string that I make dynamically. At the end I've got this:

```
fullcondition: "5439=5436 or 5439=5438"
```

The variable fullcondition contains `"5439=5436 or 5439=5438"` with these double quotes.

fullcondition is used after in an if statement and that's why I need to remove double quotes.

```
if ("5439=5436 or 5439=5438")
```

does not work
What I need is:

```
if (5439=5436 or 5439=5438).
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `fullcondition.replace("\"", ""); `

Comment: Additionally, I feel like you might be under the impression that you will now be able to write `if (fullcondition)` and expect to evaluate the string contents as the condition.  Which is not the case.  Just so you know.

Comment: Even without quotes that's not a valid conditional expression. SHow where this string is created

Comment: Also in JS, comparison is using == or === and not = which is assignment

Comment: @LukePark: You'd have to use `.replace(/"/g, "")` to replace more than just the first one. Not that I think there are actually any quotes in the OP's string in the first place. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I always forget about that in JS.  You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like:

```
var x = "5439=5436 or 5439=5438".replace(/=/g, '===').split(' or ');

if ( eval(x[0]) || eval(x[1]) ) {
    // some code
}
```

but [using eval can be dangerous :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

**EDIT:** without `eval`:

```
var x = "5439=5436 or 5439=5438".split(' or ');
var left = x[0].split('=');
var right = x[1].split('=');

if (left[0]===left[1] || right[0]===right[1]) {
    // some code 
}
```

or shorten:

```
var x = "5439=5436 or 5439=5438".replace(' or ', '=').split('=');

if (x[0]===x[1] || x[2]===x[3]) {
    // some code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the eval to evaluate a string:

```
eval("5439==5436 || 5439==5438")
```

But this assumes you have done some regex to convert your expression to something javascript can interpret.